# Qt how to draw a smooth circle with QGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a graphics view with a QGLWidget viewport. Format of the widget is QGL::SampleBuffers. I want to draw a smooth circle. I tried QPainter::Antialiasing but it did not remove jagged appearence. What are the other options that could be helpful for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are drawing the circle as lines using GL_LINES (or GL_LINE_STRIP or GL_LINE_LOOP). Check your display driver settings if the antialiasing is enabled there. Note that some display cards (for example in old laptops) do not support antialiasing at all.

Comment: No, I am drawing the circle in paint() function of a graphics item and I am using drawEllipse().

Comment: Is the antialising enabled in the display driver settings?